# Sum Odd/Even rows of grouped data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
df_cost = pd.DataFrame({"Product": ["A","A","A","A","B","B","C","C"],
                    "Cost":[1000,10,2000,15,3500,15,5000,5]})
```

In here every odd row of the same product is the cost and the even row is the quantity. So what I would like to do is to groupby by a product and then sum all odd rows and even rows separately for each product and divide one by another to get the average price.

I tried to use the nth() method but it only chooses one specific row, so I can separate data in the cases where I have only two rows but as you see each product has an unequal (although always even) number of rows.

Any thoughts?

Comment: are we grouping each product as well? or it is just even and odd rows to consider?

Comment: "every odd row _of the same product_" made me think so. But I would like some clarity on how average price is calculated because if one is quantity and the other is price then wouldn't the computation be like `(1000 * 10 + 2000 * 15) / 3000`?

Comment: For product `A` for example it would be `(1000+2000)/(10+15)`, For product `B` it's just `3500/15`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`groupby sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-sum) on "product" and % on the index then [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html#pandas-dataframe-unstack):

```
df = (
    df_cost.groupby(['Product', df_cost.index % 2]).sum()
        .unstack()
        .droplevel(0, 1)
)
```

`df`:

```
            0   1
Product          
A        3000  25
B        3500  15
C        5000   5
```

Then calculations can be done on the `0`/`1` columns:

```
df[0] / df[1]
```

```
Product
A     120.000000
B     233.333333
C    1000.000000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Yeah, that worked like a charm. So `unstack` just separates specified indices? What does `droplevel` do? Thanks

Comment: So you can run without the `unstack` and the `droplevel` to see how it changes the shape of the DataFrame. It's just to make the shape more useable.